# How to get List from Django Model (instead of Map of fields)

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have a Model called Patient. In this table I have a field:`id` and `condition`. So, If I want to get the `id`s given the condition, I can use this following syntax.

```
ids = list(Patient.objects.filter(condition='sick').values(id))
```

So the ids will contains a list of map:

```
ids = [{id: 123}, {id=345}, ...]
```

However, instead of map, I want to simply get the list like shown below:

```
ids = [123, 345, ...]
```

How can I achieve this from Django query?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Patient.objects.filter(condition='sick').values_list(id, flat=True)
```

Comment: This should work. See in [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) for more.